# Identity Comparisson in `in` in Python

Tags: python, comparison

In python:

```
>>> 1 in [True, False]
True
```

Is there a way to achieve an `in` statement with identity comparison as in `is` instead of `==`?

e.g.

```
>>> True is in [True, False]
True
>>> 1 is in [True, False]
False
```

Comment: As if python wasn't psuedo code enough to begin with you want to bring it to the next step ey?

Comment: `any(1 is value for value in {True, False})` vs. `any(True is value for value in {True, False})`

Comment: For this example `isinstance(1, bool)` might be enough.

Comment: I agree with Matts second option. The best way to handle multiple types is check the type to make sure it is what you want. Such as `isinstance(2, int) and 2 in [2, 4, 6]`, first you make sure the type is what you expect, then do the contains check,.

Comment: @Matthias I would put those two options in an answer. There may be a better way but for now those two combined make a solid answer.

Comment: Let someone else make an answer from my comments. I'm tired (`Out of coffee error.`).

Comment: The questions is simplified. `isinstance(bool)` will work for the displayed case, but not if checking against a large number of items in the list. I prefer the first answer by @Matthias as it is flexible.

Comment: The duplicate specifically asks for something that is not like `is`. I want something that is `is`.

Answer (score -2):

try out this function, it works exactly you expect :

```
    def is_func(var, list_):
        for each in list_:
            if var is each:
                return True
            else:
                continue
        return False
```

Here I have used "continue" explicitly to visualize the flow of code, for 
new programmers. You can remove the "else" part of the code for simplicity and
less code.

This is how it works:

```
    >>> is_func(True, [True, False])
    True
    >>>is_func(1, [True, False])
    False
```

Comment: This answer will not work for `is_func(1, [True, 1, False])`. The `return False` statement should only happen if the for loop is exhausted. @Matthias's comment is much more compact as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I will make the change immediately

Comment: The continue is unnecessary. This is better solved with an `any` statement as it is more compact and will also perform the necessary short-circuiting.

Comment: I  know that. But being more explicit, it makes it more understandable for newbies

Comment: Explicit use of `continue` at the end of a for loop is bad code. It is entirely unnecessary and only adds more complexity. If someone were to need to add something later at the end of the for loop, it would return early unless they remembered to delete the extraneous `continue`. This is just asking for more bugs to appear.

Comment: I am just providing a simple solution to a simple problem.I am not programming a source code for a space shuttle.As long as the code is working as expected, there is no problem with it, everyone has their own programming style. And also the function I wrote, is not even causing any exceptions. I wrote this code for newbies to understand the flow of code.And if anyone is using my function to program a space shuttle, then I think they are smart enough to make changes according to their needs, for this simple problem.I think you have enough brains to understand what I am trying to state here.